# How can I make Discord Bot detect emoji reaction and click(trigger) it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So my question is

Scenario:
Lets say there's a bot in my server that sends an embed message with the title "Hello", And adds a random reaction under it which acts like a trigger.

What I want to do:
I want my bot to detect the title of that embed message and if it matches to my if statement then it also clicks/adds the same reaction that the embed bot put under it.
If there's any confusion please let me know.

Comment: Do you want this detection on new messages that have been sent since the bot has been running, cached messages + new messages, or all messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will only work on new messages and cached messages,

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
  const message = reaction.message;
  const embeds = message.embeds;
  //return if no embeds or if another user reacted instead of the bot itself
  if(!embeds.length || user.id !== message.author.id) return;

  const firstEmbed = embeds[0];

  //add your logic here
  if(firstEmbed.title !== "Hello") {
    //react same
    message.react(reaction.emoji);
  }
});
```

For filtering out embeds you might need reference to

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.2.0/class/MessageEmbed

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I did try to upvote you but apparently I can't do it right now because of my score and stuff ;_;. Tho anyways I appreciate it alot!

Comment: No problem. As the OP you're only job is to answer questions and accept any answer that worked, so don't worry